# Change previous element in DOM on hover using CSS

Tags: html, css, hover

I don't think this is possible in CSS, but maybe I'm wrong! Here's my HTML:

```
<div class="thumb_ctn">
    <div class="overlay">
        <div id="link_text">SOME LINK TEXT</div>
    </div>
    <figcaption>SOME OTHER TEXT</figcaption>
</div>
```

When hovering over figcaption, I need to change the opacity of "overlay" from 0 to 1.

Is there a CSS solution to this or do I need to use Javacript to move up the DOM?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no such selector.
CSS is "walking" down the DOM.
Ofcourse you can achieve that with javascript though.

Comment: In this particular case, why not apply the :hover to "thumb_ctn"?